# DateTime minute format :00

Tags: c#, datetime, model-view-controller

I don't manage to display right minute format.
Only have the first number of minute (fe: `17:0` for `17:00` and `14:3` for `14h03`)

What's wrong with the format?

My view:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HeureEvenement.Hour):@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.HeureEvenement.Minute)
</td>
```

My model:

```
[Column("HEURE_EVENEMENT")]
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Heure de début: ")]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "HH:mm tt")]
public DateTime HeureEvenement { get; set; }
```

Comment: You are displaying two numbers (which happen to be hours and minutes), not one date/time where the format could apply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) your `DataFormatString` in attribute should look like

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm tt}")]
```

And you should display it like

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HeureEvenement)
</td>
```

because `.Hour` and `.Minute` is integer and it will be rendered as integer, not like datetime

or you can directly write format in the view as

```
@item.HeureEvenement.ToString("HH:mm")
```

instead of `.DisplayFor` usage

---

Actually you can modify your code as

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HeureEvenement.Hour.ToString("00")):@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.HeureEvenement.Minute.ToString("00")
</td>
```

and it will always display 2 digits for hours and 2 digits for minutes. But it will take more time if you will want to modify output format